# How to find first and last values giving the same result in an integer array, map, hashset etc.?

Tags: java, android

Here is some pseudo code to explain my question.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> values1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] list1 = {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    int[] list2 = {3,2,1,5,4,3,6,5,4};

    for (int id : list1) {
        values1.add(id);
    }

    for (int id2 : list2) {
        values2.add(id2);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
        results.add(values1.get(i)+values2.get(i));

    }

    System.out.println(results.toString());
```

The result is :

```
[6, 6, 6, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15]
```

And my question is:

How can i get only the first and last pairs of values that give the same results?

So in this case:

```
[3,3] [5,1]
[6,5] [8,3]
[9,6] [11,4]
```

I hope I've explained it clearly.

Comment: So both lists have the same length?

Comment: Yes they will always have the same lenght and always all values that gives the same results will be next to each other like in my example

Comment: values1+values2  is a sum of integers, returns the value of the operation...
you need som kind of array for pair... int[] pair= new int[2] and another collection type catching this values, sorry but your logic is not clear.  if(pair[0].equals(pair[1]){collection.add(pair):}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are positive, you could do this:

```
List<List<Integer>> firsts = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Integer>> lasts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> prevPair = null;

for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
  List<Integer> thisPair = Arrays.asList(values1.get(i), values2.get(i));
  List<Integer> prevFirst = firsts.isEmpty() ? null : firsts.get(firsts.size()-1);
  if (getSum(thisPair) != getSum(prevFirst) ) {
    if (prevPair != null) {
      lasts.add(prevPair);
    }
    firsts.add(thisPair);
  }
  prevPair = thisPair;
}
lasts.add(prevPair);

System.out.println(firsts.toString()); // [[3, 3], [6, 5], [9, 6]]
System.out.println(lasts.toString()); // [[5, 1], [8, 3], [11, 4]]
```

The `getSum()` method would be:

```
public static Integer getSum(List<Integer> list) {
  return list != null ? list.get(0) + list.get(1) : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int[] firstPair = null;
int[] lastPair = null;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i ++) {
    int current1 = list1[i];
    int current2 = list2[i];

    if (current1 != current2) {
        continue;
    }

    if (firstPair == null) {
        firstPair = new int[] { current1, current2 };
        continue;
    }

    if (lastPair == null) {
        lastPair = new int[2];
    }

    // always update the content of the lastPair as you find 2 similar values.
    lastPair[0] = current1;
    lastPair[1] = current2;
}
```

Which then you could store in an Array like data structure or a pair `Tuple` class, only allocating the space for 2 elements.

e.g:

```
int[][] result = new int[][] { firstPair, lastPair };
```

or if the signature of your methods is required to be a List:

```
List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>(2);
result.add(firstPair);
result.add(lastPair);
```

p.s: don't forget to test the null values, depending on your requirements, at the moment of returning or at the moment of reading the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();

    first.add(values1.get(0));
    second.add(values2.get(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            if (results.get(i) != results.get(i - 1)) {

                first.add(values1.get(i - 1));
                second.add(values2.get(i - 1));

                first.add(values1.get(i));
                second.add(values2.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    first.add(values1.get(results.size() - 1));
    second.add(values2.get(results.size() - 1));
```

result :

```
first :  [3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11]
second : [3, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4]
```